# Taylor's series and nth derivitive

Tags: taylor-expansion

The problem is: Calculate the Taylor's series in "$a=1$" of the function : 
$$f(x)=(5x-4)^{-\frac{7}{3}}\ .$$ I've started off by calculating the $n$th derivative of a function :
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=-\frac{7}{3}\cdot5\cdot(5x-4)^{-\frac{10}{7}}\\
f''(x)&=\frac{7}{3}\cdot\frac{10}{3}\cdot5\cdot5\cdot(5x-4)^{-\frac{13}{7}}\\
f'''(x)&=-\frac{7}{3}\cdot\frac{10}{3}\cdot\frac{13}{3}\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot(5x-4)^{-\frac{16}{3}}
\end{align}

$$f^{(n)}(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\cdot5^n\cdot(5x-4)$$
I am stuck finding the nth derivative... Could you please help me with that?
After that I am said to calculate the convergence of the obtained order.
Should I use the ratio test when $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}\ ??$$

Comment: just a little correction, in the first two derivatives denominator is 3 not 7 !!

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=-\frac 73\times 5\times (5x-4)^{-10/3}=(-1)\times \frac 73\times 5\times (5x-4)^{-(7+3)/3}$$
$$f''(x)=\frac 73 \times \frac{10}3\times 5\times 5\times (5x-4)^{-13/3}=(-1)^2\times  \frac  73 \times \frac{7+3}3\times 5^2\times  (5x-4)^{-(7+2\times 3)/3}$$

So the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative should be:

$$\large{f^{(n)}(x)=\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (3k+7)\right)(-1)^n\left(\frac 53 \right)^n(5x-4)^{-\frac{7+3n}{3}}}$$
$$\large{a_n=f^{(n)}(1)=\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (3k+7)\right)(-1)^n\left(\frac 53 \right)^n}$$